The input string '1.7976931348623157E+308' was not in a correct format
I upgraded my .NET 8 solution to .NET 9 and replaced SwaggerGen with the new OpenAPI that .NET 9 provides. This is how everything related to this feature is setup in my program:
...

builder.Services.AddOpenApi("dev");

...

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.MapOpenApi();
    app.MapScalarApiReference();

    app.UseHttpLogging();
}

...

app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
    ctx.Request.EnableBuffering();
    await next(ctx);  // -> exception 
});

...

I'm getting System.FormatException and this is the call stack:

at System.Number.ThrowFormatException[TChar](ReadOnlySpan`1 value)
at System.Number.ParseDecimal[TChar](ReadOnlySpan`1 value,
NumberStyles styles, NumberFormatInfo info)
at System.Decimal.Parse(String s, IFormatProvider provider)
at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi.JsonNodeSchemaExtensions.ApplyValidationAttributes(JsonNode
schema, IEnumerable`1 validationAttributes)
at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi.OpenApiSchemaService.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__2(JsonSchemaExporterContext
context, JsonNode schema)
at
System.Text.Json.Schema.JsonSchema.g__CompleteSchema|104_0(JsonNode
schema, <>c__DisplayClass104_0& )
at
System.Text.Json.Schema.JsonSchema.ToJsonNode(JsonSchemaExporterOptions
options)
at
System.Text.Json.Schema.JsonSchema.ToJsonNode(JsonSchemaExporterOptions
options)
at
System.Text.Json.Schema.JsonSchema.ToJsonNode(JsonSchemaExporterOptions
options)
at
System.Text.Json.Schema.JsonSchema.ToJsonNode(JsonSchemaExporterOptions
options)
at
System.Text.Json.Schema.JsonSchemaExporter.GetJsonSchemaAsNode(JsonTypeInfo
typeInfo, JsonSchemaExporterOptions exporterOptions)
at
System.Text.Json.Schema.JsonSchemaExporter.GetJsonSchemaAsNode(JsonSerializerOptions
options, Type type, JsonSchemaExporterOptions exporterOptions)
at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi.OpenApiSchemaService.CreateSchema(OpenApiSchemaKey
key)
at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func2 valueFactory)
at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi.OpenApiSchemaStore.GetOrAdd(OpenApiSchemaKey
key, Func`2 valueFactory)
at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi.OpenApiSchemaService.d__6.MoveNext()
at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi.OpenApiDocumentService.d__33.MoveNext()
at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi.OpenApiDocumentService.d__31.MoveNext()
at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi.OpenApiDocumentService.d__21.MoveNext()
at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi.OpenApiDocumentService.d__20.MoveNext()
at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi.OpenApiDocumentService.d__19.MoveNext()
at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi.OpenApiDocumentService.d__12.MoveNext()
at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.OpenApiEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()

Update (providing more info):
I was able to reproduce it in a new project, create a new ASP.NET Core Empty project (.NET 9) and replace the Program.cs with the following content:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddOpenApi();

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapOpenApi();
app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");
app.MapPost("/price", ([FromBody] MyModel model) => model.Price);

app.Run();

class MyModel
{
    [Range(1, double.MaxValue)] // I cannot use decimal.MaxValue
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

now run the project and navigate to /openapi/v1.json:


"I'm getting System.FormatException" - at what point? Is this when you start the app, or when a client sends a request? If so, what's in the request? What does the OpenAPI spec look like? Are you generating the OpenAPI classes, or using handwritten ones? Please provide much more information.

You haven't posted the API or DTOs so one has to guess. Just posting the line app.MapOpenApi(); doesn't help. Post enough code to reproduce the problem and nothing more. Does your DTO have a double or decimal property? Does it have validation attributes? The call stack contains ApplyValidationAttributes and ParseDecimal. If .NET 8 has an actual problem you should be able to reproduce it with with the Minimal API template, just by adding your DTO and a call that accepts or returns it.

By the way removing all double.MaxValues fixed that error.
